# Guy went to prison, found a ghost, planned revenge

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie about 5 years ago. A guy in his mid-20s goes to prison for some reason and the warden is a total jerk. Later it turns out that the warden killed his nephew for trying to escape and buried his remain in the basement of the prison behind a brick wall.

This guy starts seeing this dead dude and he tells him his story. Later the guy "befriends" the warden and things get out of control.

It's an older movie, probably 90s or early 2000s.

Comment: How long ago is "some time ago"? How old is "an older movie"?

Comment: older movie: between '90 and 2000, some time ago: 5 years